# Using scope guards as code contracts

Tags: c++, code-contracts, design-by-contract

So we're investigating the use of scope guards or some similar mechanism to ensure incoming/outgoing object validity and/or internal state invariance, similar to C# Code Contracts.

In the specific case where an unexpected condition/exception arises in the middle of normal processing that causes some objects to be left in an inconsistent state, what mechanism could/should we use to side-step the fact that the scope guard is going to complain when we jump out of the function?

Here's some sample pseudocode to illustrate my point:

```
struct IObjectValidator;

struct ObjectValidatorScopeGuard
{
  ObjectValidatorScopeGuard(IObjectValidator * pObj) 
    : m_ptr(pObj) 
  {
    Assert(!m_ptr || m_ptr->isValid());
  }

  ~ObjectValidatorScopeGuard()
  {
    Assert(!m_ptr || m_ptr->isValid());
  }
  private:
    IObjectValidtor * m_ptr;
};


int SomeComponent::CriticalMethod(const ThingA& in, ThingB& inout, ThingC * out)
{
  ObjectValidatorScopeGuard sg1(static_cast<IObjectValidator *>(&in));   
  ObjectValidatorScopeGuard sg2(static_cast<IObjectValidator *>(&inout));
  ObjectValidatorScopeGuard sg3(static_cast<IObjectValidator *>(out));

  // create out
  try
  {
     out = new ThingC();
     out->mergeFrom(inout, out); // (1)
  }
  catch (const EverythingHasGoneHorriblyWrongException& ex)
  {
     // (2) out and inout not guaranteed valid here..
  }
  return 0;
}
```

So if something goes wrong in (1) that causes 'out' or 'inout' to be in a bad state at point (2), the scope guards sg2/sg3 are going to throw exceptions... and those exceptions could mask the true cause.

Is there any pattern/convention to work with this scenario? Are we missing something obvious?

Answer (score 6):

In case of an exception in the block of code guarded by your object validator, the C++ runtime will call `terminate`. You cannot throw exceptions, as your destructor does, while  other exception is being handled. Therefore you should not throw exceptions from destructor ([details here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.9)). Instead of throwing an exception you should use assert or log the error.

Still better than checking invariants is to guarantee that they will never be broken. That is called [exception safety](http://www.boost.org/community/exception_safety.html). Basic exception safety (preserving the invariants) is usually easy to achieve just by clever reordering of statements and using [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Example of exception safety techniques:

```
class String {
  char *data;

  char *copyData(char const *data) {
    size_t length = strelen(rhs->data);
    char *copy = new char[length];
    memcpy(data, rhs->data, length);
    return data;
  }

public:
  ~String() { delete[] data; }

  // Never throws
  void swap(String &rhs) { std::swap(data, rhs->data); }

  // Constructor, Copy constructor, etc.
};

// No exception safety! Unusable!
String &String::operator = (String const &rhs) {
  if(&rhs == this) return *this;

  delete[] data;
  data = copyData(rhs->data); // May throw
}

// Weak exception safety
String &String::operator = (String const &rhs) {
  if(&rhs == this) return *this;

  delete[] data;
  data = 0; // Enforce valid state
  data = copyData(rhs->data); // May throw
}

// Strong safety 1 - Copy&Swap with explicit copy
String &String::operator = (String const &rhs) {
  String copy(rhs);// This may throw
  swap(copy);// Non-throwing member swap
  return *this;
}

// Strong safety 2 - Copy&Swap with pass by value
String &String::operator = (String rhs) {
  swap(rhs);// Non-throwing member swap
  return *this;
}
```

Comment: D'oh! Silly me for forgetting no-throw-in-dtors :-) Our ASSERT macro actually throws aswell, so clearly we're barking up the wrong tree. Any pointers for determining the correct 'clever reordering of statements'?

Comment: +1, scope guards are for maintaining state, not making assertions. Also, since `Assert` doesn't actually throw anything in this context, you might as well use a regular `assert` macro.

Comment: @JBRWilkinson: I am not able to find an example on the Internet now, so I have just added a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting to put an assertion in a scope guard. It's not the usual use case, but not a bad idea to improve their coverage.

Just be aware that you can't throw another exception when you're already handling one. So a problem with `in`, `out`, or `inout` can't be delegated somewhere else, you need to take care of it immediately.

If all you want is to print a debug message when the assertion is violated (expected behavior for `Assert`), then simply print the message and continue on your way… don't mess with exceptions at all.

If `Assert` should tie into a greater exception handling mechanism, then exception objects should have structure to accommodate whatever `Assert` actually produces. *But* getting that state into the appropriate exception object is nontrivial. `Assert` is called during stack unwinding, before the exception has been handled, before it's accessible by rethrow i.e. (`try { throw; } catch ( structured_e & ) {}`). You would need a thread-local variable to store the current structured exception, initialized by `structured_e::structured_e()`.

Long story short, my advice is to provide a separate `WeakAssert` for use in destructors and scope guards which doesn't throw an exception.

See also [Herb Sutter's article](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/047.htm) on why not to be clever when combining exceptions and destructors.